# How to save the list data in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, output

I am doing a to-do list web page using HTML/JavaScript, I did only display the content entered by users with priority bases. I need to save that content in local storage using JavaScript(Entered content must be present after refreshing the page also).

Below you can see my code. I believe I should use an array for that but I dont know how to use local storage 'get item', 'set item', 'JSON.stringfy' and 'JSON.parse'. Please, can you help me?

```js
function Changecolor() {
  var lists = document.getElementsByClassName('task-list')[0];
  btn_colors = {
    'hi': 'hiP',
    'med': 'medP',
    'low': 'lowP'
  }
  radios = document.getElementsByName('rgPrior');

  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      btn_selected_color = (btn_colors[radios[i].value]);
      break;
    }
  }
  var todo = document.getElementById('item').value;
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  entry.className = btn_selected_color;
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo));
  lists.appendChild(entry);
}
```

```css
.hiP {
  background-color: red;
}

.medP {
  background-color: blue;
}

.lowP {
  background-color: green;
}

.ch5 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="txtAdd">New thing to do:</label>
  <input name="txtAdd" type="text" id="item" />
  <input type="button" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" value="Add List" onClick="Changecolor()" />
</form>
<p>Set Priority</p>
<p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="hi" id="rgPrior_0"/>High</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="med" id="rgPrior_1"/>Medium</label>
  <br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="low" id="rgPrior_2"/>Low</label>
  <br/>
</p>
<ul class="task-list" id="store"> </ul>

<button>Delete</button>
```

Comment: You have those four keywords :)

Comment: I don't see where you've attempted to do so. Please do some reading on the subject, make an attempt, and revise to ask a more specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` converts a JavaScript array/object to a string which can be saved in `localStorage`, and `JSON.parse()` converts the string saved in `localStorage` to a JavaScript array/object.

CodePen link (doesn't work on StackOverflow)

https://codepen.io/LuisAFK/pen/ZEKLLEZ

Comment: Hi bro, please help me, I also want to clear the data(specific selected list) after completion of work, by using the delete button.

Comment: @VidhyaSagar I added a CodePen link

Comment: Thank you so much brother from bottom of my heart it helps me a lot.